# How can I get Data int Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I made list page pagination. 
i want make some pagination number list. 
but i don't know how can i get data in jade.

```
-for(var i=0; i < #{totalCnt}; i++){
                 form(action='/topic')
                     input(type='button' name='nowPage' value=i) 
             -}
```

This is my Jade code 
`#{totalCnt}` is not working

```
app.get("/topic", function(req, res) {
  var nowPage = req.query.nowPage;
  //전체 리스트를 띄우는 기본 리스트 화면
  var sqlCnt = "select count(*) from topic";
  var sql = "SELECT id, title FROM topic ORDER BY id";
  client.query(sqlCnt, function(err, res3) {
    client.query(sql, function(err, res2) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        if (nowPage == null || nowPage == "" || nowPage <= 1) nowPage = 1;
        var totalCnt = res3.rows;
        res.render("view", {
          topics: res2.rows,
          totalCnt: totalCnt,
          nowPage: nowPage
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

this is my javascript code to get data 
`#{}` is correct grammar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already pass the variables with the `res.render` function to the `view` file. Make Sure, that the view file is named `view.pug`. You passed the name of the `.pug` file as first parameter `"view"`.

In the [pug specs (interpolation)](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) you can find the following:

> If you need to include a verbatim #{, you can either escape it, or use interpolation.

You can use the variables from the render function in your template like this:

#### app.js

```js
app.get("/topic", function(req, res) {
    var nowPage = req.query.nowPage;

    client.query("select id, title from topic order by id", (err, result) => {

        if (!nowPage || nowPage === 1)
            nowPage = 1;
                
        res.render("view", {
            title: 'Topics',
            topics: result.rows,
            totalCnt: result.rowCount,
            nowPage: nowPage,
            errors: err
        });
    });
});
```

#### view.pug

```
h1 #{title}
p There are !{totalCnt} topics on !{nowPage} page

if topics
  ul
    for topic in topics
      li ID: #{topic.id}, Title:  #{topic.title}
else if errors
  ul
    for error in errors
      li!= error.msg
```

Note: I didn't escaped the count values (I used the `!{}` syntax) because the count values are calculated.

Comment: ```-for(var i=1; i <=totalCnt; i++){
                     input(type='submit' name='nowPage' value=i) 
              -}``` this is my solution. I already solved it. But, thank u for answer it.